# gb4e example with two-paragraphed footnote throws error

Tags: footnotes, paragraphs, linguistics, gb4e

`gb4e` is a useful package for writing linguistics papers, as it allows one to append judgments to examples, via the optional argument of `\ex{}`.

As such, I would like to retain the use of this package, but I have just run into a problem. I'm not sure what is going on internally, but it seems that `gb4e` prevents paragraph breaks from occurring anywhere within the scope of the required argument of `\ex{}`.

In particular, I have a footnote attached to an example to clarify an aspect of the example. If I try to put a paragraph break inside of this footnote, using either a blank line or the TeX primitive `\par`, an error is thrown.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
    \ex[]{An example requiring a footnote\footnote{A footnote with two paragraphs.\par Here's the second paragraph.}}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

And the resulting error:

> Runaway argument? {An example requiring a footnote.\footnote {A
>   footnote with two parag\ETC. ./test.tex:8: Paragraph ended before \@ex
>   was complete.  
>                      \par  l.8 ...ootnote{A footnote with two paragraphs.\par
>                                                      Here's the second paragra...
>
> ?

Is it possible to achieve a multiple-paragraphed footnote inside of a `gb4e` example, or is there a workaround that would allow me to retain the use of `gb4e`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change `\par` onto `\endgraf`. (The height of the page is intentionally reduced on a picture).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
 %   \ex[]{An example requiring a footnote\footnote{A footnote with two paragraphs.\par Here's the second paragraph.}}
\ex[]{An example requiring a footnote\footnote{A footnote with two paragraphs.\endgraf Here's the second paragraph.}}
\end{exe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some discussion on *what* this solution is doing, see [When is it better to use \par than \endgraf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96865).