# Translate multi-paragraph strings with translations package

Tags: translations

I'm trying to create a localized document template including some boilerplate text blocks, using the `translations` package. Everything's working great so far, except I cannot declare translations spanning multiple paragraphs.

Whenever the translation string contains a paragraph break, compilation aborts with the following error:

> ERROR: Paragraph ended before \NewTranslation was complete

I have tried wrapping the message inside an `\mbox` without success.
Is there a way to have a translated message spanning multiple paragraphs?

I'm not really invested in the translations package, so if there's a better way to achieve my result, please let me know! :)

Here's a minimal working example illustrating the problem:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{translations}

\NewTranslation{ngerman}{template}{%
  Erster Absatz.

  Zweiter Absatz.
}

\begin{document}
\GetTranslation{template}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for posting a MWE.  Unfortunately all of the `translations` macros are defined as 'short' macros, i.e., ones that don't support `\par` inside them. I assume this is by design. You might want to contact the package author.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @AlanMunn! I had feared that this was the case - would you happen to know any good replacements to the translations package?

Comment: The `translator` package (part of `beamer`) can deal with paragraphs in translation definitions.  I don't know much about either package however, to decide between them.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'll implement this into `translations`. I didn't foresee that one might want long translations…

Comment: I just uploaded v1.6 ([GitHub](https://github.com/cgnieder/translations/releases/tag/v1.6)) to CTAN which allows paragraphs in translation replacements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the macros in the `translations` packages are defined as short macros which don't allow `\par` inside them.  I assume this is by design.  (Now that the package author has replied in the comments, it seems like this can be addressed as a feature request.)

The `translator` package, which is part of `beamer` does seem to allow paragraphs in translation definitions, however. Perhaps this can be useful for your task:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{translator}

\newtranslation[to=German]{template}{%
  Erster Absatz.

  Zweiter Absatz.
}

\begin{document}
\translate[to=German]{template}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

As a temporary solution, you may be able to get away with using `\endgraf` instead of `\par` in your translations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{translations}

\NewTranslation{ngerman}{template}{%
  Erster Absatz.\endgraf
  Zweiter Absatz.
}

\begin{document}
\GetTranslation{template}
\end{document}
```

But this has its drawbacks, depending on context. See the following question for discussion.

- [When is it better to use \par than \endgraf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96865/2693)

Comment: Of course there's always `\endgraf` :)

Comment: @clemens I forgot about that. Is it really a viable (temporary) solution?

Comment: @clemens The drawback with `\endgraf` is that it doesn't vary its behaviour like `\par`. (Try `\begin{itemize} \item Foo\endgraf Bar.  \item Foo\par Bar.  \end{itemize}`) It depends on the context the string will be used in.

Comment: The \endgraf workaround suits my needs for now, since the template text will not appear inside complex environments. I will also consider the translator package for a more permanent solution!

Comment: @AdrianoKF Actually, given Clemens' response to you, you should probably not switch to the `translator` package, but simply wait for the new version of `translations` to be released.

Comment: Ah, I missed his comment above - in this case I will stand by for his update and use your workaround in the meantime. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: `\endgraf` is just a copy of the primitive `\par` so it depends on where you use it like @Nicola already said. Another option is `\newcommand\fakepar{\par} ` and use that.

Answer (score 1):

**REVISION**

This will accomplish it fully, requiring only that the template be expandable.

It takes (under the redefined name `\NewTranslation`) input including paragraphs, and parses through the `\par`s, converting them to `\fauxpar`s.  It calls on a saved version of the original `\NewTranslation`, using the input version containing the `\fauxpar` surrogates.  Finally, one can call on `\GetTranslation` as in the original answer above.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{translations}

\let\fauxpar\par
\let\svNewTranslation\NewTranslation
\renewcommand\NewTranslation[3]{%
  \def\tmp{}%
  \MyNewTranslationAux#3\par\relax%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname#2Aux\endcsname{\tmp}%
  \svNewTranslation{#1}{#2}{\csname#2Aux\endcsname}
}
\makeatletter
\long\def\MyNewTranslationAux#1\par#2\relax{%
  \g@addto@macro{\tmp}{#1}%
  \if\relax#2\else\g@addto@macro{\tmp}{\fauxpar}\MyNewTranslationAux#2\par\relax\fi%
}
\makeatother

\NewTranslation{ngerman}{templateA}{%
  Erster Absatz.
}
\NewTranslation{ngerman}{templateB}{%
  Erster Absatz.

  Zweiter Absatz.
}
\NewTranslation{ngerman}{templateC}{%
  Erster Absatz.

  Zweiter Absatz.

  Third Absatz.
}
\begin{document}
\GetTranslation{templateA}\medskip

\GetTranslation{templateB}\medskip

\edef\foo{\GetTranslation{templateC}}
\foo
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL SIMPLER APPROACH**

Depending on your need, this answer may be wholly unacceptable, or it may get you out of a pinch.  If one uses a surrogate `\fauxpar` macro for your input replacement for `\par`, it will work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{translations}

\NewTranslation{ngerman}{template}{%
  Erster Absatz.
\fauxpar
  Zweiter Absatz.
}
\let\fauxpar\par
\begin{document}
\GetTranslation{template}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this looses the expandability of `\GetTranslation`…

Comment: @clemens Can you elaborate, since I know nothing of what this package does?

Comment: `\edef\foo{\GetTranslation{blah}}` works, `\edef\foo{\MyGetTranslation{blah}}` doesn't…

Comment: @clemens I remedied the issue.